# Security of Ubuntu flavours, especially Kubuntu

Tags: security, release-management

Does Kubuntu gets the same level of OS security as Ubuntu with the Unity desktop?

Does Ubuntu developers offer special security updates to the unity desktop, or security is only dependent on the ubuntu base, so even if I install any flavour, I get the exact same level of security?

Or it is dependent on the developers of that certain derivative?

Answer (score 4):

All [official flavours](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives) of Ubuntu, including Kubuntu, use the same repositories.

Canonical commits to providing security updates to software in the `main`, and `restricted`, sections of the repositories. From the [Security Team FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ):

> What software is officially supported by the Ubuntu Security team?
>
> - Ubuntu is currently divided into four components: `main`, `restricted`, `universe` and `multiverse`. All binary packages in
>     `main` and `restricted` are supported by the Ubuntu Security team for
>     [the life of an Ubuntu release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TimeBasedReleases), while binary packages in universe
>     and multiverse are supported by the Ubuntu community.

Typically, only the packages in the standard Ubuntu flavour's installation disks are in `main` or `restricted`. That means that a lot of software in Ubuntu GNOME, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, etc. are *not* in `main`:

```
$ apt-cache show gnome-shell konqueror | grep Section 
Section: universe/gnome
Section: universe/web
```

Note how both these packages, crucial to Ubuntu GNOME and Kubuntu respectively, are from the `universe` section.

Support for the `universe` and `multiverse` sections is done by the community, specifically, [the Masters of the Universe (MOTU)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU). This means that Canonical makes no guarantees about them. The [MOTU Update Procedures](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/UpdateProcedures) describe when and how they provide updates.

So, no matter which flavour you install, you will get the same level of support for some software, and a different level for the rest - after all, even with the standard Ubuntu, after installation, you might install software from the `universe` section, such as [VLC](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vlc).